# Taking screenshots of webpages with phantomjs and asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, phantomjs

I'm trying to take screenshots of urls, and save the screenshots on my server. I am using phantomjs to take the screenshots. 
I've found some sample codes online, but it wont work in my application.

It seems to get stuck in the DoWhile method.

However when I run phantomjs from cmd.exe it works fine.

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://www.google.com google.png
```

In my project I have a folder called "Phantomjs", which has the phantomjs.exe and the rasterize.js script.

Do you have any pointers what I'm doing wrong?

```
private static void GrabUrl(String url)
        {
            string serverPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Phantomjs/");
            string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss") + ".png";

            new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(x =>
            {
                ExecuteCommand("cd " + serverPath + @" & phantomjs rasterize.js " + url + " " + filename + @" ""A4""");
            })).Start();

            var filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Phantomjs/"), filename);

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] bytes = DoWhile(filePath);


        }

private void ExecuteCommand(string Command)
    {
     try
     {
      ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
      Process Process;

      ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " + Command);
      ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

      Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
     }
     catch { }
    }


    private byte[] DoWhile(string filePath)
    {
     byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
     bool fail = true;

     while (fail)
     {
      try
      {
       using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
       {
           bytes = new byte[file.Length];
           file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
       }

       fail = false;
      }
      catch
      {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
     }

     System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
     return bytes;
    }
```

Removing the try/catch block in Execute command did nothing. I do get an exception:

```
Exception:Thrown: "Could not find file 'C:\ ~\Web API\Phantomjs\28042014_042756.png'." (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
A System.IO.FileNotFoundException was thrown: "Could not find file 'C:\~\Web API\Phantomjs\28042014_042756.png'."
Time: 28-Apr-14 16:28:00
Thread:Worker Thread[2068]
```

Comment: Has it produced the actual screenshot file?

Comment: When I run it from cmd, it creates it. From the code above, it doesnt create anything. Just gets stuck in the DoWhile Method...

Comment: Take out the empty catch block on `ExecuteCommand` and see what happens.

Comment: Like @RobH mentioned, this means the problem is in ExecuteCommand :)

Comment: Just as some architecture/security to ponder, do you really want your website to run under an account that's able to execute arbitrary commands on the server?

Comment: I think you should directly execute phantomJs

Comment: Good point, probably not :) I just need to see if I can grab screenshots of urls a user submits. Thanks for the help though!